# Excessively long tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, character-limit

"combinatorial number theory"

"linear fractional transformations"

The software forbids these two tags because they are too long. Should the length limits be adjusted? Or is there some way of making special exceptions?

Comment: I think the length limits should be extended.

Comment: Somewhat related past questions: [Is the moment-generating-functns tag spelled wrong on purpose?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22691) and [Fixing the newly created “geometric-invariant-theor” tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25323).

Comment: On this site, you have recently created ([tag:combinatorial-number-th]), there also is ([tag:combinatorial-group-th]) (both these tags have empty tag-info).  On MO there are tags called ([combinatorial-group-theor](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-theor)) and ([combinatorial-number-theo](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-number-theo)).

Comment: Tags combin-number-theory, combin-group-theory, and linear-fractional-transf would seem reasonably easy to understand.

Comment: Why couldn't a question just be tagged with both [tag:combinatorics] and [tag:number-theory]? For the second one: [tag:mobius-transformations] is shorter.

Comment: @J.M. for about the same reasons we do not just tag questions on [tag:analytic-number-theory] with [tag:analysis] and [tag:number-theory]

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that on the question where (combinatorial-number-theo) was created, this tag was [replaced in the meantime](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2068044/revisions) by ([tag:combi-number-theory]). (It seems that that tag has been around for some time before that question.)

Comment: The character limit has been [expanded to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490). Thanks to Daniel Fischer, we now already have ([tag:combinatorial-number-theory]) and ([tag:combinatorial-group-theory]) tags - see [Expanding abbreviated tag names](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26776).

Answer (score 9):

> Should the length limits be adjusted?

For the most part 25 characters suffice, and it is also a road-block against exaggeration in tag names. Say, I would not want to see tags like [limits-at-infinity-without-lhospital-involving-trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-at-infinity-without-lhospital-involving-trigonometric-functions).

However, it is a fact, and you gave some example, that there are some legitimate and natural tag names that are longer than 25 characters. Thus, I think at least something more flexible than a hard limit would be desirable.

> Or is there some way of making special exceptions?

As far as I know, no. On some sites they came up with the workaround of chopping up the tag name and then creating synonyms to piece things together. But, this is not a real solution either.

Thus,  for the cases you mention, I propose to use abbreviations, like contracting the 'theory.'

Here is an old and somewhat popular feature request on the main Meta site

[Increase limit on tag length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209248/increase-limit-on-tag-length)

Comment: Using the compactness theorem, if every abbreviated term has a tag, then the expanded, whole term has a tag!

Comment: If absurd tags like the one you mention are created, could there not be some routine way of discussing them and deleting them when that is appropriate?

Comment: @MichaelHardy sure, all I meant to say is that there is also some merit in having a rather tight bound. Also, having *some* bound for the input-field is more-or-less a technical necessity to avoid attacks. The question then is what does one take exactly. I agree that something a bit longer than 25 would be better. In a prior life [I already wrote about this](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/968).